# Converting snmptrap command to python (pysnmp or alternative)

Tags: python, pysnmp, snmp-trap

I can send an snmptrap (net-snmp-utils) command from the shell, equivalent to -

```
snmptrap -v2c -c public myhostname.com '' .1.3.6.1.4.1.1234.7.0.1 .1.3.6.1.4.1.1234.7.1 s desktop 1.3.6.1.4.1.1234.7.2 s "TESTING" .1.3.6.1.4.1.1234.7.3 s CODE
```

I am trying to do the same via python3. The trap messages sent from the script are received and processed by the server/agent/manager. However the ones from python (code and output pasted below) are are not successfully reaching the server.

So far I've been using pysnmp

```
from pysnmp import debug
debug.setLogger(debug.Debug('msgproc'))
from pysnmp.hlapi.asyncore import *
next(sendNotification(
    SnmpEngine(),
    CommunityData('public', mpModel=1),
    UdpTransportTarget(('myhostname.com', 162)),
    ContextData(),
    'trap',
    NotificationType(
        ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.2')
    ).addVarBinds(
        ( '1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.3.0', '.1.3.6.1.4.1.1234.7.0.1'),
        ('.1.3.6.1.4.1.1234.7.1', OctetString('desktop')),
        ('1.3.6.1.4.1.1234.7.2', OctetString('TESTING')),
        ('.1.3.6.1.4.1.1234.7.3', OctetString('CODE'))
    )
))
```

The output is

2019-05-03 12:16:02,881 pysnmp: StatusInformation: {'errorIndication': AccessAllowed()}
2019-05-03 12:16:02,884 pysnmp: StatusInformation: {'errorIndication': AccessAllowed()}
2019-05-03 12:16:02,886 pysnmp: StatusInformation: {'errorIndication': AccessAllowed()}
2019-05-03 12:16:02,891 pysnmp: StatusInformation: {'errorIndication': AccessAllowed()}
2019-05-03 12:16:02,899 pysnmp: prepareOutgoingMessage: using contextEngineId  subtypeSpec , > encoding iso-885
9-1 payload [0x80004fb805c3c8cf48]> contextName b''
2019-05-03 12:16:02,904 pysnmp: generateRequestMsg: Message:

```
 version=1
 community=public
 data=PDUs:
  snmpV2-trap=SNMPv2TrapPDU:
   request-id=10163951
   error-status=noError
   error-index=0
   variable-bindings=VarBindList:
    VarBind:
     name=1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0
     =_BindValue:
      value=ObjectSyntax:
       application-wide=ApplicationSyntax:
        timeticks-value=0

    VarBind:
     name=1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0
     =_BindValue:
      value=ObjectSyntax:
       simple=SimpleSyntax:
        objectID-value=1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.2

    VarBind:
     name=1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.3.0
     =_BindValue:
      value=ObjectSyntax:
       simple=SimpleSyntax:
        objectID-value=1.3.6.1.4.1.1234.7.0.1

    VarBind:
     name=1.3.6.1.4.1.1234.7.1
     =_BindValue:
      value=ObjectSyntax:
       simple=SimpleSyntax:
        string-value=desktop

    VarBind:
     name=1.3.6.1.4.1.1234.7.2
     =_BindValue:
      value=ObjectSyntax:
       simple=SimpleSyntax:
        string-value=TESTING

    VarBind:
     name=1.3.6.1.4.1.1234.7.3
     =_BindValue:
      value=ObjectSyntax:
       simple=SimpleSyntax:
        string-value=CODE
```

On adding 'io' to the debugger I get this at the end - is it a standard message or does it mean that the message was queued and did not leave?

2019-05-06 04:55:42,914 pysnmp: sendMessage: outgoingMessage queued (164 octets)
00000: 30 81 A1 02 01 01 04 06 70 75 62 6C 69 63 A7 81

Comment: When you say 'not reaching', what exactly do you mean? Not reaching on network level or your manager ignoring the message? If you add *io* to the debugging, you should see if pysnmp sends the blob and where exactly if it does. Maybe tcpdump'ing on the network when you generate TRAP by net-snap vs pysnmp and finding differences would reveal something?

Comment: I added 'io' option to debugger and get outgoing message queued message (edited the output in question above).

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on pysnmp but problem seems like coming from snmp settings. Did you make the arrangements for agent? please check http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpd.conf.html for settings like version, rwusers, groups etc.
If you want alternatives you can check:
https://github.com/pief/python-netsnmpagent
and 
https://github.com/hosthvo/pyagentx

netsnmpagent cant sent traps but you can add that spec by yourself.

I recommand pyagentx. Using the main agent is a bit difficult however you can create your agentx and extend it. But do not forget to make settings over snmpd.conf.

Answer (score 0):

Your message has not been sent because the main loop has not been started.

You should probably import `pysnmp.hlapi`, as opposed to `pysnmp.hlapi.asyncore`, because the former eventually defaults onto `pysnmp.hlapi.asyncore.sync`, which runs main loop internally for just one query.

The `pysnmp.hlapi.asyncore` module is asynchronous. That means that besides submitting a message you also need to run the main loop (`snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()`). You can find an [example](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/hlapi/asyncore/agent/ntforg/common-notifications.html) on asynchronous use, but it seems you need just sync version for now.